# `brew list` shows many things I did not install. Why? If something installed depends on them, how do I know?

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-managers

On a new machine, I used brew to install only four things: `git`, `node`, `sqlite` and `less`. Later on, when I ran `brew update` I was told many other things that I didn't install were "outdated". I ran `brew list` and got the following:

```
brotli              less               pcre2
c-ares              libnghttp2         python@3.9
ca-certificates     libuv              readline
gdbm                mpdecimal          sqlite
gettext             ncurses            xz
git                 node
icu4c               openssl@1.1
```

Where did these come from? If they were installed because `git`, `node` or `less` needs them, how do I find out?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, Homebrew (aka brew), like all package managers, automatically installs dependencies. This is a recursive process: If the dependency itself has dependencies, brew will install them too, and so on.

### `brew deps`

You can see the dependency tree for anything you installed using the `brew deps` command:

```bash
> brew deps node --tree

node
├── brotli
├── c-ares
├── icu4c
├── libnghttp2
├── libuv
├── openssl@1.1
│   └── ca-certificates
└── python@3.9
    ├── gdbm
    ├── mpdecimal
    ├── openssl@1.1
    │   └── ca-certificates
    ├── readline
    ├── sqlite
    │   └── readline
    └── xz
```

You can see in this tree many of the things you saw in `brew list`.

### `brew uses`

But to answer your question, you can go in the opposite direction using the `brew uses` command:

```bash
> brew uses readline --installed

node            python@3.9            sqlite
```

The `--installed` flag is important, because without it the above command will list *everything* that uses `readline`, whether it is installed on your system or not. Notice also how `brew uses` is recursive (in the opposite direction as `brew deps`), showing both `python@3.9` which uses `readline` directly, and `node`, which uses it indirectly.

### `brew desc`

Now if you're curious as to what any of these installed dependencies do, use the `brew desc` command:

```bash
> brew desc pcre2

pcre2: Perl compatible regular expressions library with a new API
```

### `brew leaves -r`

If you just want the short list of what you specifically installed, `brew leaves -r` will work for *most* cases:

```bash
> brew leaves -r

git
less
node
sqlite
```

`brew leaves` lists things installed that aren't dependencies (they are leaves in the above tree), and the `-r` filters the list to those thing you installed manually.

I said "most cases" because it won't include things that you installed manually but are no longer leaves. This happens when you install another thing that depends on something you originally installed manually. For example, if I had installed `readline` manually, `brew leaves -r` would show it at first, but not after I install `node` or `sqlite`.

For a lot of people, "leaf" and "installed manually" will be the same thing. But the more you install the more likely this will be wrong.

### `brew bundle dump --file -`

This is a harder command to remember (Create an alias!), but it gives a more reliable, complete answer than `brew leaves -r`:

```bash
> brew bundle dump --file -

brew "git"
brew "less"
brew "node"
brew "sqlite"
cask "rar"
```

It's more complete because unlike `brew leaves` it will include things you installed manually even if they are no longer leaves. In addition, it includes taps and casks.

I learned this trick from [@orlp's answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/438632/263076).

Comment: Beautiful response, thanks! Minor note: `brew leaves` doesn't technically list what you've installed, but just what is installed and not a dependency of something else. You may well find leaves that you didn't install. `brew autoremove` can remove those for you.

Comment: @SeanConnolly thanks both for the compliment and the correction. I'll update the answer, and I can do the research myself, but offhand do you know how you can end up with leaves that you didn't install? Are they residual artifacts of uninstalls that failed to clean up after themselves? I always thought Homebrew uninstalled all non-leaves if all its parents were uninstalled.

Comment: @orlp referencing your Ask Different answer here. I wish there was a better way to list things one manually installed. `brew bundle dump --file -` isn't perfect, including taps and casks you didn't intentionally install.

Comment: Great answer. To note is that [since Homebrew 3.6.0](https://brew.sh/2022/09/07/homebrew-3.6.0/), `brew desc pcre2` is not by default valid; you have to type `brew desc --eval-all pcre2`. This apparently is a security measure since it may execute untrusted code.

Comment: @skagedal Yes, I noticed that too. I had decided to leave it as-is in my answer because users would see the warning and could decide for themselves whether they wanted to use `--eval-all` or to set `HOMEBREW_EVAL_ALL`. Also, I was kind of hoping the Homebrew folks would find a better solution. It seems to me they could reimplement `desc` in some way that was secure, so that the simple command would work. But clearly they haven't (yet). I [opened an issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/16733). Let's see how they respond before I update the answer.